# Generating a Confusion Matrix from a Seaborn Heatmap

Tags: confusion-matrix, seaborn, heatmap

Is there a way I can reverse engineer a Seaborn heatmap saved as .png? I want to get the array of values out of it. Does the library provide a "load-from-image" facility, or is there any sta

Comment: Do you only have access to the .png file?

Comment: Yes. Shortly put, let's say I saved N confusion matrices into .png heatmaps, but now I want to compute an "average" between them, without re-running the very time-consuming pipeline. Is that possible?

Comment: I would highly doubt it. Even if you could get the information back from the colors, they will likely be aggregates, making an average between them difficult. You're likely better off to re-run your pipeline. And in the future, save both the actual confusion matrix data, and its image.

Comment: Right. The source of the confusion matrices is RASA NLU's evaluator. I will probably just clone their source and make so that it saves both and re-run. Thank you for your time!